# Ubuntu server users question

Tags: linux, apache-2.2, ubuntu, security

I have read this article:

https://help.ubuntu.com/9.04/serverguide/C/user-management.html

But it doesn't go into depth with the privileges section.

I need to know how to set privileges of me (as a user).

I am the only user, but I want access to everything, but I don't want to manage my VPS logged in as root. So I am creating a username.

Anybody have a list of privileges, what they mean and how to set them?

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [Users in ubuntu; Cant figure it out](http://serverfault.com/questions/145582/users-in-ubuntu-cant-figure-it-out)

Comment: Did you get sudo set up as instructed in the above linked question?

Comment: Also...this question is probably more well-suited to be moved over to Superuser. I would flag it as such, but have already flagged it as a dupe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Linux doesn't have a "list of privileges" per se. Permissons to do certain things are controlled using file user/group ownership and then by setting the read/write/execute flags appropriately. Get yourself set up with sudo as I suggested you do in [this](https://serverfault.com/questions/145582/users-in-ubuntu-cant-figure-it-out/145584#145584) case, and you will be able to run all commands as root.

Comment: I have done what You said in the other Q. But, if I now create a user, will that user have all permissions by using sudo? Is this the way to do things really?

Comment: If you're granting access in your sudo file using usernames, then you'll need to add each new user to that file. You can also grant sudo access by group, in which case the new user would just need to be added to the appropriate system group.

Comment: So you mean it is the same thing to add users to the sudo file, as in adding the users to an appropriate group with appropriate permissions?

Comment: Oh, and yes, this is the way to "do things", whatever that means.

Comment: As long as that group has been granted permissions via sudo, then yes, the effective access will be the same as if you had granted access by username.

Answer (score 0):

Users do not have privileges; files have permissions and ownership. The only user that has special privileges is `root`, which is why system administration is done as that user after switching to it via `su` or `sudo`.